# Dotted rectangle on logo wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

Good morning all,
I am currently developing a site on Wordpress and would like to remove the dotted rectangle when I click on my logo.
thank you in advance[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18JV4.png)

Comment: can you provide the website link ?

Comment: yes of course : https://www.lecrasformation.fr/

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of tag "`<a>`" outline properly.

Add this to your css.

```
a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

if above code didn't work then try this (change `<a>` color from this `#1490d7` to `transparent`)

```
a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
      color: transparent;
    }
```

Add above code at the end of `css/colors/default.css` or edit
the below code on default.css

```
body a:focus, body a:hover {
    color: #1490d7;
}
```

Comment: I tried both and still not work... I have some css. files, maybe i don't take the good one ? Screenshot of my files : https://snipboard.io/15TS3O.jpg

Comment: i updated the answer:[change  css/colors/default.css]

Comment: Here is my code relative to a {}. This is in editor-style.css  https://snipboard.io/sxpNY9.jpg

Comment: Thank you ! I add these lines : `body a:focus, body a:hover {
    outline: none;
 color:transparent;
} `
And it's working but the outline appears fast (0,2 second). Do you have any solution for that ? You can check on the website. Thank you for all :)

Comment: .. add a:active

Comment: Thank you ! It's always here but it's ok